# $f$ is continuous relative to $A$ at, 2

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $A = (0,1] \cup \{2\}$, considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that every function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous relative to A at 2.

My attempt:

For $f$ to be continuous at 2. $\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists  \delta > 0$ such that:

$f(B_{\delta}(2)) \subset B_{\epsilon}(f(2))$. Now, $B_{\delta}(2))$ is an open set in A and hence we can claim that $f$ is continuous at 2 relative to $A$.

Comment: $f$ is not assumed to be continuous? You can't start the proof assuming something stronger than you are trying to prove!

Comment: @copper.hat Then how should I proceed ?

Comment: In the usual way with continuity, Fix $\epsilon>0$ and find a $\delta>0$ such that ...

Comment: @copper.hat First, I have to prove that $f$ is continuous. Since, $f$ is not defined how am I suppose to use the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition ?

Comment: No. You have to show that for **any** $f$ that it is continuous at $x=2$. You cannot show that $f$ is continuous everywhere because it need not be. But it **must** be continuous at $x=2$.

Comment: You need to consider the particular structure of $A$ here.

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited my attempt. Will it work now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98880/discussion-between-shakunimama-and-copper-hat).

Comment: No. You haven't proved anything. You have just stated that for any $\epsilon>0$ that there exists some $\delta>0$ blah blah blah. You have to **prove** that some such $\delta>0$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're given $\varepsilon>0$. You take $\delta=1$, whatever $\varepsilon$ is.

Then for this $\delta$: $$B_\delta(2)=\{x \in A: d(x,2) < 1 \} = \{2\}$$

and certainly it is the case that $f[B_\delta(2)]  =\{f(2)\} \subseteq B_\varepsilon(f(2))$, as $f(2) \in B_\varepsilon(f(2))$.

The point is that you have to take the structure of $A$ into account and pick a **specific** $\delta$ for the situation. You cannot just claim that "the ball is open and so is its image" for any $f$ you don't know anything about; it's bound to be false in general.. You have to apply the definition: give a concrete $\delta$ for any $\varepsilon >0$ and then give a valid reasoning. See above.